# Problems with delete function with different row ID form

Tags: php, html, forms, sql-delete

i have some problems with variable value in input.

So for easier understanding. I have some client informations in mysql database, which i output with php in table. And i am working now on delete option.

It must work like, when i click on button it grabs ID of row and then i send ID of row to delete.php and it's deleted.

But now i have problems, because for example if i have 10 rows ( 10 different clients ), everytime i got ID from first row,

please check below my code and try to help me out where its mistake, so why i dont get the right row ID in form.

```
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "
    <table align='center' width='962px' style='color:#000; font-family:Tahoma;'>
        <tr>
            <td width='5%' height='35'><center><span class='text3'>" . $row['id'] . "</span></center></td>  
            <td width='22%' height='35'><center><span class='text3'>" . $row['imeinpriimek'] . "</span></center></td>
            <td width='18%' height='35'><center><span class='text3'>" . $row['datuminkrajrd'] . "</span></center></td>
            <td width='25%' height='35'><center><span class='text3'>" . $row['datumvnosa'] . "</span></center></td>     
            <td width='30%' height='35'> 

    <form action='delete.php' method='post' id='form'>

    <button type='button' style='border: 0; background: #fff;' onclick=\"popup('Želiš izbrisati spodaj navedenega klienta?<br><br> <b>" . $row['imeinpriimek'] . "</b>')\"><img src='images/delete.png' title='Izbriši'><input type='text' name='id' value='" . $row['id'] . "' /</button>



    <div id='dialog-box'>
    <div class='dialog-content'>
    <div id='dialog-message'></div>

    <button type='submit' onclick=\"$('#form').submit()\" style='border:1px solid #125e94; border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; font-size:12px; width: 30px; height: 25px; text-align:center; color: #e6e4e2; background: #0397ff;'>Da</button> 

    <button style='border:1px solid #125e94; border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; font-size:12px; width: 30px; height: 25px; text-align:center; color: #e6e4e2; background: #0397ff;'>Ne</button>
    </form> 
    </div>
    </div>

    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    ";
    }
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: please show the server side code where you process the input as well

Answer (score 0):

All your forms have the same id, while it has to be unique. Change:

```
<form action='delete.php' method='post' id='form'>
```

to

```
<form action='delete.php' method='post' class='form'>
```

And

```
<button type='submit' onclick=\"$('#form').submit()\">Da</button>
```

to

```
<!-- No need to use onclick, since this is type="submit" button -->
<button type='submit'>Da</button>
```

Comment: Thank you dfsq  for help, but looks like problem is not fixed.

Comment: a bit strange to mark an answer as accepted but then state that it did not solve the problem...

Comment: Because at first try i though that is working, but then i saw that its not working... i unmarked this answer as accepted now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give each form a unique id. maybe change the line

```
 <form action='delete.php' method='post' id='form'>
```

to

```
 <form action='delete.php' method='post' id='form". $row['id']."'>
```

and you need to change the line with the submit button referencing the form as well:

```
<button type='submit' onclick=\"$('#form".$row['id']."').submit()\" style='border:1px solid #125e94; border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; font-size:12px; width: 30px; height: 25px; text-align:center; color: #e6e4e2; background: #0397ff;'>Da</button>
```

But as dfsq pointed out in his anser, you actually don't need the `onclick` part in a `submit` type button

It depends a bit how you process the form data on the server side when you get it. Note that you also miss to give unique ids for other `<div>` like `dialog-box` and `dialog-message`. This results in invalid html. I am not sure however, if that causes the problems.

Comment: basically yes. In my solution i give the form an id, but that must be repeated in the button line

Comment: what is the result. maybe i got mixed up with the ```"``` and ```'```

Comment: Result is the same, every row is getting the same ID ( it tooks ID from first row )

Comment: Could you possibly post a few rows of the HTML output?